# Can't create dictionary from json in swift

Tags: json, swift, object, dictionary, response

I Have this json object which is downloaded by dataTaskWithRequest, i download it and serialize it like this:

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
completion(json)
```

then the completion looks like this:

```
(let json) in
if let dict = JSON{
    completion(dict)
}
```

and last completion looks like this:

```
(let response) in
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
    if let resp = response{
        if resp["status"] as? Int == 0{
            let user = resp["user"]
            if let dict = user{
                print(dict)
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

problem is that, it returns object like this:

```
 {"created": "2016-06-01T10:49:54.096000",
 "data_source": "1",
 "display_name": "My Name",
 "email": "Some@string.com",
 "fb_id": "",
 "first_name": "My",
 "gender": "0",
 "google_id": "",
 "id": "SomeId",
 "last_name": "Name",
 "phone": "Number",
 "updated": "2016-06-01T10:49:54.096000"}
```

when i try to cast this object in [String:AnyObject] it returns nil, and i can't get the values from this last object, can anybody help me with this, i've been trying to do this for like 4 hours and couldn't get it done

Comment: you get nil in step 1 ?

Comment: i get nil when i try this in step 3 if let dict = user as? [String:AnyObject]

Comment: put the real print of user maybe helpful

Comment: heres the real print of user

Comment: this print like a string not a dictionary,  if it's a dictionary may print look like { "key" = "value" }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113515/discussion-between-nikagar4-and-wilson-xj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
if let dictString = user as? String{
        if let data = dictString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding){

            let dic = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments)
            print(dic)
        }
}
```